# What is this electric plug called?

Tags: electrical, generator, cord-and-plug

I need to buy a replacement for a twist-locking electric plug that looks like this:

[image]

Picture of the socket:

[image]

Searching online I can't seem to find anything that matches. The closest thing I found are NEMA twist-lock plugs, but they have a different locking\ground pin.

Can someone identify this plug type?

Comment: NEMA isn't just one layout: https://www.stayonline.com/reference-nema-locking.aspx

Comment: It doesn’t appear to match any NEMA configurations. I take it from the Arabic? writing it is not from a NEMA region. Apparently you need to search the country of origin for replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.gamut.com/p/hubbell-non-nema-turn-locking-plug-general-use-3-contacts-20-a-current-MjM2MTc4), which looks like the right one. You didn’t list specs so I just went off of looks. Called a Non-Nema.

Comment: Ooh, voltage may be too high. The one I posted is a 250. But I’m guessing that’s the place to talk to.

Comment: That's a maximum rated voltage, not a requirement. The plug doesn't change voltage of a circuit in any appreciable way.

Comment: HBL9965G seems like the correct P/N for that plug, BTW, according to [this chart](https://www.stayonline.com/reference-non-nema.aspx)

Comment: There are a few types of 220 V plugs in the US, depending on amperage and maybe phases.  I have one for 20 A and one for 30 A that are both different from the picture. I also have one like the picture that is dedicated to an electric clothes dryer and has two 30 breakers ( so ,can't be three phase.)

Comment: And this answer is now useless because the link has died.  Link-only answers aren't durable.

Comment: Wasn’t link only, I note it’s called a Non-Nema, search any major electrical suplly house to narrow it down, such as Grainger.com